# Java swing game JPanel layout assistance

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm in the process of making a game which has 3 sections to the JFrame, the game map, a "player view" : just an animation of the player moving and will hopefully include different enemy designs later and finally a inventory section I haven't started on yet.

What would be the best way in terms of class and method layouts to have all these 3 sections of my JPanel able to communicate with one another and dynamically change based on the current situation (having the player view show an enemy when their tile collides with another or have it not update if the player doesnt move (s)).

I don't mind re-writing the entire game just this is my first game and would like some assistance on structure.

And I'm not sure exactly how paintComponent works or repaint() method. Or how draw(Graphics g) is called
to make the graphics???

Code for context and testing:

TextGamePanel.java :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class TextGamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final int HEIGHT = 30, WIDTH = 30, MAPVISIBILITY = 8;
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1080;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private static final int UNIT_SIZE = 36;
    private static final int DELAY = 10;
    private String[][] mapBlank = new String[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    private ArrayList<Enemies> enemyList = new ArrayList<Enemies>();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Players player;
    private int turnCounter = 0;
    Timer timer;
    boolean active = false , movementMade = false;

    TextGamePanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }
    public void startGame(){
        newPlayer();
        active = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }
    public void makeMap(){
        for(int row = 0; row < mapBlank.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < mapBlank[row].length; col++){
               mapBlank[row][col] = "";
            }
        }
        for(Enemies enemy : enemyList){
            mapBlank[enemy.getXPos()][enemy.getYPos()] = " *";
        }
        mapBlank[player.getXPos()][player.getYPos()] = " ^";
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){

        makeMap();
        // These loops generate the 
        g.setColor(new Color(69, 69, 69));
        g.fillRect(1080, 0, 840, 360);
        g.setFont(new Font("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 36));
        g.setColor(new Color(74, 74, 74));
        for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
            g.drawString(randomString(50), 1020, UNIT_SIZE + x*UNIT_SIZE/2);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++){
                g.setColor(new Color(0+x*10, 0+x*10, 0+x*10));
                g.setFont(new Font("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 10+x*2));
                g.drawString(randomString(200), 1020, 268 + x * 8);
            }
        }

        //makes the map background grey
        g.setColor(new Color(69, 69, 69));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        //Makes light for context of player view range
        g.setColor(new Color(227, 201, 109, 50));
        g.fillOval((int)(((player.getXPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - MAPVISIBILITY/2 * UNIT_SIZE), (int)(((player.getYPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - MAPVISIBILITY/2 *UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY +1) * UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY +1) * UNIT_SIZE));
        g.setColor(new Color(227, 180, 109, 50));
        g.fillOval((int)(((player.getXPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - (MAPVISIBILITY/2 - 1) * UNIT_SIZE), (int)(((player.getYPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - (MAPVISIBILITY/2 - 1) *UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY -1) * UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY -1) * UNIT_SIZE));
        g.setColor(new Color(240, 110, 67, 50));
        g.fillOval((int)(((player.getXPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - (MAPVISIBILITY/2 - 2.5) * UNIT_SIZE), (int)(((player.getYPos()) * UNIT_SIZE) - (MAPVISIBILITY/2 - 2.5) *UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY -4) * UNIT_SIZE), (int)((MAPVISIBILITY -4) * UNIT_SIZE));
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        g.setFont(new Font("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 36));

        //draws the grid
        for(int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE; i++){
            g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE; i++){
            g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
        }
        
        //draws only yourself and enemy around you given MAPVISIBILITY/2 = view range
        int xIndex = -1, yIndex = -1;
        for(int row = player.getXPos() - MAPVISIBILITY/2; row < player.getXPos() + 1 + MAPVISIBILITY/2; row++){
            xIndex ++;
            for(int col = player.getYPos() - MAPVISIBILITY/2; col < player.getYPos() + 1 + MAPVISIBILITY/2; col++){
                yIndex++;
                try{
                    g.drawString(mapBlank[row][col], row * UNIT_SIZE, (col + 1) * UNIT_SIZE);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }

        // inventory section (yet to be made)
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(1080, 360, 840, 720);
    }

    public void movementPhase(){
        turnCounter ++;
        updateEnemyMovement();
        if(turnCounter == 2){
            turnCounter = 0;
            newEnemy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(active){ 
        }
    }

    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_Q: // Move diagonal left up.
                    if(player.getXPos() > 0 && player.getYPos() > 0){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() - 1);
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() - 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_E: // Move diagonal right up.
                    if(player.getXPos() < HEIGHT - 1 && player.getYPos() > 0){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() + 1);
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() - 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_Z: // Move diagonal left down.
                    if(player.getXPos() > 0 && player.getYPos() < WIDTH - 1){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() - 1);
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() + 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_C: // Move diagonal right down.
                    if(player.getYPos() < WIDTH - 1 && player.getXPos() < HEIGHT - 1){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() + 1);
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() + 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_W: // Move up.
                    if(player.getYPos() > 0){
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() - 1);
                        movementMade = true; 
                    } 
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_X: // Move down.
                    if(player.getYPos() < WIDTH - 1){
                        player.setYPos(player.getYPos() + 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_A: // Move left.
                    if(player.getXPos() > 0){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() - 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_D: // Move right.
                    if(player.getXPos() < HEIGHT - 1){
                        player.setXPos(player.getXPos() + 1);
                        movementMade = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_S: // Dont Move.
                    movementMade = true;
                    break;
            }
            if(movementMade){
                movementPhase();
                movementMade = false;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void updateEnemyMovement(){

        Iterator i = (Iterator) enemyList.iterator();
        Enemies enemy = new Enemies();

        while(i.hasNext()){
           enemy = (Enemies) i.next();
           enemy.move(player.getXPos(), player.getYPos());
           if(enemy.getXPos() == player.getXPos() && enemy.getYPos() == player.getYPos()){
               i.remove();
           }
        }
     }

    public void newPlayer(){
        player = new Players(random.nextInt((int)SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE), random.nextInt((int)SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE));
    }
    public void newEnemy(){
        enemyList.add(new Enemies(random.nextInt(HEIGHT), random.nextInt(WIDTH)));
    }
    public String randomString(int n) {
 
        int leftLimit = 49; //'0'
        int rightLimit = 122; //'z'
        int targetStringLength = n;
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
            int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int) 
              (random.nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit + 1));
            buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
        }
        String generatedString = buffer.toString();
    
        return(generatedString);
    }
}

`

Players.java :
```

public class Players{

```
private int x, y;

public Players(){

}
public Players(int x, int y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
/** Positional Methods */
public int getXPos(){
    return x;
 }
 public int getYPos(){
    return y;
 }
 public void setXPos(int x){
    this.x = x;
 }
 public void setYPos(int y){
    this.y = y;
 }
```

}

`

Enemies.java :

```
public class Enemies {

    private int x, y;

    public Enemies(){

    }
    public Enemies(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    /** Positional Methods */
    public int getXPos(){
        return x;
     }
     public int getYPos(){
        return y;
     }
     public void setXPos(int x){
        this.x = x;
     }
     public void setYPos(int y){
        this.y = y;
     }
     /** Enemy Movement Method */
     public void move(int playerX, int playerY){
        if(getXPos() == playerX && getYPos() == playerY){ // x = playerX & y = playery
           }/** Diagonal right down */
           else if(getXPos() < playerX && getYPos() < playerY){ // x < playerX & y < playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() + 1);  // x + 1
              setYPos(getYPos() + 1);  // y + 1
           }/** Diagonal right up */
           else if(getXPos() > playerX && getYPos() < playerY){ // x > playerX & y < playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() - 1);  // x - 1
              setYPos(getYPos() + 1);  // y + 1
           }/** Diagonal left down */
           else if(getXPos() < playerX && getYPos() > playerY){ // x < playerX & y > playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() + 1);  // x + 1
              setYPos(getYPos() - 1);  // y - 1
           }/** Diagonal right up */
           else if(getXPos() > playerX && getYPos() > playerY){ // x > playerX & y > playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() - 1);  // x - 1
              setYPos(getYPos() - 1);  // y - 1
           }/** Down */
           else if(getXPos() < playerX && getYPos() == playerY){ // x < playerX & y = playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() + 1);  // x + 1
           }/** Up */
           else if(getXPos() > playerX && getYPos() == playerY){ // x > playerX & y = playerY
              setXPos(getXPos() - 1);  // x - 1
           }/** Right */
           else if(getXPos() == playerX && getYPos() < playerY){ // x = playerX & y < playerY
              setYPos(getYPos() + 1);  // y + 1
           }/** Left */
           else if(getXPos() == playerX && getYPos() > playerY){ // x = playerX & y > playerY
              setYPos(getYPos() - 1);  // y - 1
           }
      }
}

`

TextGameFrame.java :
```

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextGameFrame extends JFrame{

```
TextGameFrame(){

    this.add(new TextGamePanel());
    this.setTitle("Text Game");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

}

`

TextGameMain.java :

```
public class TextGameMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new TextGameFrame();

    }
}

`
```

Comment: You have done the correct thing to use a list of enemy entities and a map array, this will be effective for a small game. Those lists are what you should use to do your painting and you can use an event or a timer to detect when a player and an enemy are in the same location and render everything accordingly because all of your Panel components can access the list/map.

Comment: Just how would I go about rendering everything accordingly, would it just be by formulating a fair few if statements within the draw() method?

Comment: Yes, use a loop to run through the map and draw the visible tiles on of the map view (offset by the x/y location of where the map sits), and use the same loop to draw to the player view, and do the same for the enemies. Note that you could use a glass plane (A component that sits on top of another) to act as your minimap so that you don't have to try and render it all to one single JPanel, but have a separate section for your map and animation area. If you want very complex/detailed textures and animations then swing components may not be the best fit, and there are a lot more considerations.

Comment: You'll want to do some research into the "model-view-controller" concept, which would also include, among others, the "observer pattern".  Essentially, you have a "model" which represents the data, each view will take that model and represent the data based on their functionality.  You'd use one or more observer patterns to notify the interested parties when some kind of state changes